# Subsitution command in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$string =~ s/(\w+)/\u$1/g;
```

I am unable to understand what  `\u$1` is doing in above command.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\u` turns next following character to uppercase. So it will change first character in your captured string to uppercase.

So for example:

```
my $string="hello";
$string =~ s/(\w+)/\u$1/;
```

will give you output `Hello`.If you wish to change all the characters to uppercase then you should try

```
$string =~ s/(\w)/\u$1/g;
```

This is documented in [perlre under Escape sequences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)

> \u          uppercase next char (think vi)

Comment: Odd switcharoo `+` vs `/g` here.  For the first case (the OP's), I'd prefer `s/(\w)/\u$1/`; the `+` is not just extraneous, it might be wasteful.  For the "all the characters" case, I'd prefer `s/(\w+)/\U$1/g` (note `\U`, not `\u`); here the lack of `+` might be wasteful. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$n` variables contain the parts of the string that matched the **capturing groups** in the pattern for last regex match if the match was successful.

```
$string =~ s/(\w+)/\u$1/g;
```

In above example string will replace with capture group and every first word of string will replace with uppercase `\u`.

See this:

```
my $string = 'foo bar';
$string =~ s/(\w+)/\u$1/g;
print $1, "\n";
print $string, "\n";
```

If you print the `$1`, it will show the capture group.

Output:

```
bar
Foo Bar
```

See all first character changed with uppercase.

See [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching) for more details about *capturing group*.

Comment: thanks alot . what it will print if I will write $2 instead of $1. Can you please elaborate more on $n.

Comment: It will not print anything. _capturing group_ is first parenthesis `()` is $1, second is $2 and so on. Please see the linked doc. For more you can have a look on [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-%241) also.

Answer (score 0):

`\u$1` allows to upper-case the first charter grouped pattern. [See Here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html)

> \u  Titlecase next character

```
my $string = "stack overflow";
$string =~m/(\w+)/\u$1/g; 
# Stack Overflow
```